# Content Provider for Google Maps Navigation App

Tags: android, google-maps, android-contentprovider

Is there documentation on the content provider for the Google maps app. I want to find the destination of the Maps app is taking the user to.

There is extensive documentation on calendar content provider but nothing on navigation or maps.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

Running `adb shell dumpsys | grep Provider`

to get a list of content providers has com.google.android.maps.NavigationAvailabilityProvider

com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.apps.gmm.navigation.util.NavigationAvailabilityProvider

but Googling it I could not find any relevant information

Comment: it is not a "public" provider so you cannot use it in your code